# Dynamically add custom view to every view controller in iOS

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, autolayout

Is it possible to add dynamically (for example by extending view controller) custom view with specific size like 50px height on bottom every view controller?

I'm using iOS8, autolayout and storybaords, I don't want to modify every single view in storyboard to add my view on bottom.

I'm trying to add in this way:

```
let view = CustomView(frame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.width, 50));
self.view.addSubview(view)
```

but view is placed over current controllers view, I need to be able to place is under controllers view, something like advert banner or Tab bar.

Comment: If you *must* do this, why not just use a UIViewController subclass that puts this view on the bottom, and then all your ViewControllers can be subclasses of this custom ViewController rather than the usual UIViewController.

Comment: I'm just looking for the easiest way to add it to my view controllers, could you give me some example of your idea?

Comment: This is probably the easiest way. Is my suggestion unclear? Have you tried writing the subclass? Have a look at the `layoutSubviews` method as well as `insertSubview(_ view: UIView, atIndex index: Int)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want the *same* view for all view controllers, I think I would just change my root view controller.

My new root view controller would have a container view to host your old root view controller, and your 50px tall view at the bottom.

Since you're using storyboards this shouldn't be to hard - I think you can do it largely without writing any code.  Drag out a new view controller.  Add a container view and your bottom view.  Set up your constraints.  Drag a segue connector from the container view to your old root view controller and set they type as "embed".  Set the entry point to the scoreboard to be the new controller.

Here's a picture.

[image]